# Why i can create this function?

Tags: c#

```
private void List<string> removeDuplicates(
    List<string> currentsites, 
    List<string> listintheformlevelsitesvisited)
{
}
```

I want to get two Lists but im getting error.
Many errors:

; expected
Identifier expected
invalid token )
invalid token >
Sysntax error (

Error   10  The type or namespace name 'listintheformlevelsitesvisited' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   9   The type or namespace name 'removeDuplicates' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

All i wanted is a simple function that get two Lists. Whats wrong ?

Comment: Thats in Form1. Can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: make all variables global, all your problem wil be solved :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A function can't return `void` and `List<string>` at the same time.

Remove one and it will be fine!

Answer (score 4):

Your function must either return `void` **OR** `List<string>`, not both.